# How to estimate the correction to the integral approximation of a discrete sum?

Tags: summation

In the following approximation,

$~\epsilon\sum_{n\in Z}  F(\epsilon n)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx~ F(x) + $ correction,

how can one estimate the `leading' order correction for small $\epsilon$?

Here the function, $F(x)$, and its all derivatives,   $F^{(n)}(x)$, drop off rapidly at $\pm \infty$ such that  the  [Euler–Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) does not help. For example, $e^{-x^{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would estimate the both the sum and the integral outside some compact by a small number (your function drops off on infinity quite fast) and then apply standard formulas on that compact for numerical integration using the trapeze/ladder approximations.

Did you try the method [from wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Integrals_over_infinite_intervals)?

Comment: What I am looking for is an alaytic and closed expression for the correction as a function of $\epsilon$.